# What is the standard way to make varied types of Users in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class

I'm starting on a project that has multiple kinds of users, basically a buyer and a seller model. Some attributes apply to buyer that don't to seller, but they share many basic user traits. If it wasn't a web app I know how to do inheritance, but what is the correct way to do this in rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept in Rails you are looking for is called [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance).

You create a base `User` model, and then subclass out different other models with `User` as the base class.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a matter of introducing the concept of roles or groups, you should add a role or group model instead so that a user can be a buyer and seller. But since it is not about a role and your goal is to have buyer and/or seller specific fields, you should have two additional models called Buyer and Seller and then have an association to each of those models in the User model. This way a User can be a Buyer, Seller, both, or even many of both.

If you at some point need a many-to-many between User and Seller (for example), then even though you can do it with HABTM, a it is a good idea to introduce a tie model and use has_many :through, so that it can have data about the relationship, etc.

Assuming you are using ActiveRecord, read through this really well before getting started: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

(Or, for edge: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make a `User` model for all basic attributes that are shared among roles/user types. Then make separate models for `Buyer` and `Seller` and `delegate` all shared attributes to the `User` model.

This approach won't scale for a lot of user types, but should be adequate for your case.

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate